# How to call all articles in get_posts() include

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I want to get posts by WP user level. I use get_posts() for getting posts and in arguments I use include parameter.

Like this:

```
$private = array(
              'numberposts' => $st_cat_post_num,
              'orderby' => $st_posts_order,
              'category__in' => $st_sub_category->term_id,
              'include' => $kbsofs_posts_arr,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
           );
```

**Here is my Complete code:**

```
global $current_user;
$kbsofs_posts = '';
if($current_user->user_level == 0) {
     $kbsofs_posts = "1,2,3 ...."; // Post IDs
} else if($current_user->user_level == 1) {
     $kbsofs_posts = "10,20,30 ...."; // Post IDs
}  else if($current_user->user_level == 2) {
     $kbsofs_posts = "100,200,300 ...."; // Post IDs
} else {
     $kbsofs_posts = '';
}
$kbsofs_posts_arr = explode(',',$kbsofs_posts);

$private = array(
               'numberposts' => $st_cat_post_num,
               'orderby' => $st_posts_order,
               'category__in' => $st_sub_category->term_id,
               'include' => $kbsofs_posts_arr,
               'post_status' => 'publish',
           );
//print_r($private);
$st_cat_posts = get_posts($private);
```

When I login as a **subscriber** or **contractor** or **author** it gives me exact articles what I want. But when I loged in as administrator it gives me nothing (I think its not working because of my else condition).

I also try this:

```
$post_include = '';
if($current_user->user_level != 10 || $current_user->user_level != 9 || $current_user->user_level != 8) {
     $post_include = "'include' => $kbsofs_posts_arr";
}
$private = array(
               'numberposts' => $st_cat_post_num,
               'orderby' => $st_posts_order,
               'category__in' => $st_sub_category->term_id,
               $post_include,
               'post_status' => 'publish',
           );
```

But it also gives me nothing. So please tell me how can i get all articles in my else condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you set `includes` to an empty string if the user isnt included in your if blocks, meaning no posts are inlcuded.

Better to only use the `include` key if needed:

```
global $current_user;

$private = array(
    'numberposts' => $st_cat_post_num,
    'orderby' => $st_posts_order,
    'category__in' => $st_sub_category->term_id,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

if($current_user->user_level == 0) {
    $private['include'] = [1,2,3];
} else if($current_user->user_level == 1) {
    $private['include'] = [10,20,30];
}  else if($current_user->user_level == 2) {
    $private['include'] = [100,200,300];
} 

$st_cat_posts = get_posts($private);
```